# List or combobox to select entries as you type

Tags: vba, excel

In an excel spreadsheet (2013) I have a listbox which contains a list of about 50 items. Is it possible to when in the list box to type "M" and for it to jump to any entries with "M"?

I know this is possible using a userform and combo box by setting the MatchEntry to 0 - frmMatchEntryFirstLetter. Is it however possible to do this using a list or combobox embedded in an excel worksheet?

Comment: I've tried but can't hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know on what version of Excel you're on, but with an ActiveX combobox you can do the same as in a userform (set the MatchEntry).

Works for me in several projects.